# Efficency of repeated arithmetic between two macros

Tags: c++, c, macros

In an ANSI C project I am working on, I have two macros defined: `PERIOD_IN_MS` and `CYCLES_PER_MS`. In the actual period handling logic, I do **many** comparisons between a counter that is incremented every ''cycle'' and `PERIOD_IN_MS * CYCLES_PER_MS`. I'm concerned that this arithmetic operation is repeatedly evaluated during each comparison.

Does anyone know if this is true, or if the compiler will evaluate the product of the two integer literals at compile time and use that instead?

I realize that this particular example would probably only remove one instruction out of the generated assembly code, but now I'm curious about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard doesn't impose any requirement to do this, but any sensible compiler will fold these constants down into one at compile-time.  See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_propagation.

If you're curious to know whether this has *actually* happened, you can always take a look at the assembler generated by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler should (but I believe in C is not required to) evaluate the constant expression at compile-time.  A good compiler will almost certainly do it, though, when optimization is turned on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid multiple evaluation, maybe just to speed up compilation *and* your constants fit into `int`, you could enforce single evaluation by using an enumeration constant, instead.

```
enum { cycles_per_period = PERIOD_IN_MS * CYCLES_PER_MS};
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to define CYCLES_PER_PERIOD as a macro?  It would eliminate the unnecessary creation of an enum.

Comment: @oosterwal: If `CYCLES_PER_PERIOD` is a macro wouldn't it just be a substitution of `PERIOD_IN_MS * CYCLES_PER_MS`? Since the processor is oblivious to the semantics of C, it doesn't actually compute this value right? The output from the preprocessor would be no different than the original scenario.

Comment: @oosterwal: what do you mean by "creation of an `enum`"? An `enum` type and the corresponding constants are only an abstraction. They don't result in any object being created or the symbol table being changed.

Comment: @okorz001, @Jens Gustedt: The problem with 'creating' CYCLES_PER_SECOND as an enum is that, in implementations that don't support `long int` enums, you are limited to `int` space. Therefore, if `PERIOD_IN_MS * CYCLES_PER_MS` exceeds the size of `MAX_INT` or if either of the previously defined macros represents a `float` value your results would be incorrect.

Comment: @oosterwal, indeed you are limited to `int` by the C99 standard. The constants forcibly have that type. Usually `int` is 32 bit so `INT_MAX` is fairly large.

Comment: @Jens:  My days are spent coding for 16-bit µControllers so I tend to think of `int` as 16 bits.